# Firejail breaks Lutris/Wine. How can I troubleshoot/fix it?

Tags: permissions, wine, lutris, firejail

Installing Firejail and running `firecfg` stops a game that I have installed in Lutris from starting. Uninstalling Firejail fixes it.

The game tries to run only for a second or 2 so running `firejail --list` doesn't help.

How can I troubleshoot/fix this?

Comment: I would advice to ask this on the firejail forums as it is about using firejail. Firejail might block anything that is proprietary so what you see to me(!) seems intended and correct behaviour.  I would assume you will need a profile...  https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/blob/master/etc/profile-a-l/lutris.profile is a template.

Comment: Yeah that's the default Lutris profile that comes with FJ, it's activated when 'firecfg' is run. The problem is it breaks Lutris for me. I'll ask on the FJ github, thx.